# Jenkins runs "make clean" really slow

Tags: jenkins, makefile

I'm new to Jenkins and I have noticed that running "make clean" is really slow.  When I look at the console output it takes ~20 seconds to create the output directories.

I'm running on windows and my build is:

- navigate to the build directory
- run "make clean && make"

I don't think it can be any simpler.

Running "make clean && make" outside of Jenkins, but on the same machine runs the entire clean and build process in less than 30 seconds.

Within Jenkins it takes:

- 3 minutes to just get through the clean
- 10 minutes to build

I must be doing something wrong.  Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Is it really the *build* (`make clean && make`) that takes so long, or is there possibly some overhead for SCM checkout, artifact handling etc...? If it's just the pure build, then for comparison purposes, please compare the runtime (in both cases) after performing an initial `make clean`, so you have the same starting conditions.

Comment: I have already factored out the SCM checkout and all the overhead.  That is not counted in my slowness.   Like I said in my original post.  It takes 3 minutes to do a clean and 10 minutes to build after the clean via Jenkins.    Not using Jenkins it's < 30 seconds for the clean and build.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue which popped up without a known change from one build to the next. Have you ever figured something out?

Comment: @arsenal the issue was I didn't create nodes to do builds.  I just created jobs and Jenkins ran them locally.  Once I created nodes to run jobs then everything run at expected speeds.

Comment: @Brian thanks for the feedback, we have set up build slaves, so our problem must be something else. So I'll be looking around some more.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **workspace location**. If your workspace is on a network share, then the build can take considerably longer than on a local drive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I checked and it is on a local drive and not a network share.